# Entity Framework Database-First with Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, entity-framework

I'm developing an ASP.NET WebForms application with Entity Framework Database-First connected with SQL Server, and I want to connect the same Entity Data Model with Oracle Database.

My concerns are:

- How to install Oracle Database Engine on my dev machine to test?
- How to connect the data model with Oracle instead of SQL Server?
- How to generate the same schema into Oracle?
- Are there drivers, tools, or apps I need to install?

Comment: I wondered if you got this working? I have a similar issue I'm trying to figure out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29242527/reference-oracle-db-tables-in-mvc5-app-instead-of-using-local-dbcontext. My MVC5 App is fully functioning with Code-First Local DBContext. I've created all the tables in Oracle and am now trying to figure out how to connect/use these Oracle tables through Entity Framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am doing exactly the same as you

i.e. Converting a ASP.NET MVC application on SQL server to Oracle.

Since your application is already running, what you can do, is

1. generate create scripts from your SQL Server database,
2. create the same tables in Oracle.
3. Install ODP.NET from
   [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html).
   This will allow you to connect to Oracle from a .NET application.
4. Now create a new `edmx` file from the tables in Oracle and if you do
   everything properly, your application should be running.

Note: ODP.NET provider is only visible if you have a VS license. It is not visible on the free version.

Comment: Its works fine for .net framework but in my case i am using .net5 can you please help

Comment: @ShivamMishra There was an issue raised for this issue. See here -https://github.com/oracle/dotnet-db-samples/issues/81. But it is closed now, I am assuming if you look at the comments, you will be able to resolve it