# Creating Oracle ADO.NET Entity Data Model not getting my existing connection

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I created a Data Connection (Oracle) in my Server Explorer. It works, I can access the tables, etc...

Now when I try to create a ADO.NET Entity Data Model and I select "Generate from database", my connection doesn't display in the drop down to the "Which data connection should your application use to connect to the database". If I click on New Connection, and click to change the data source to Oracle, it's not in the list.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and it's an MVC4 app. Trying to use Entity Framework.

Thank you!

Comment: hi, what version are you using ? check this link for see a one issue like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299654/entity-framework-6-5-connection-to-oracle

Comment: are you familiar with `ODP.NET` also look at the answer provided here to get an idea on the steps you can take 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22293952/entity-framework-database-first-with-oracle-database
[ODP.NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html)

Comment: mvc4 uses the entity framework 5

Comment: I already have odp.net installed.